# __dopostback undefined in IE 11 on windows preview 8.1

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net 4.0 application running on Windows Server 2003.

I am running Windows 8.1 *preview* with IE 11 and I am getting the

> __dopostback undefined error.

I have already tried all of the suggested hotfixes, kbs, and nuget packages and none of them work. I can add the site to the compatibility view settings and everything works fine. I googled but I cannot find any updated browser definition files for IE 11. Has anyone seen updated files or know what I can do to solve the problem.

Like I have said I have already tried everything from this [Scott Hanselman's blog article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). So please do not post that as a response.

Comment: I noticed your casing of `__doPostBack` is incorrect in your question, did you type it correctly in the code? (I've done that mistake several times ^^)

Comment: [IE 11 pretends it isn't Internet Explorer](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/), so unfortunately, the updated browser definitions that are forward compatible for browsers that call themselves IE 11 don't work.

Comment: @Christoffer it was 4am and you are correct I miss typed in my question but yes it is correct in my code, mostly because it is auto-generated.

Comment: @hvd thanks for the link to the article it explains a lot of the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: It isn't so much that IE11 pretends it isn't IE as it is IE11 becoming infinitely more standards-compliant. Perhaps, one day, we'll be completely free of the scourge of browser detection.

Comment: Do you have a possibility to upgrade your project to .NET 4.5 and test to see if it makes the difference?

Comment: Perhaps one day we'll be completely free of the scourge of Internet Explorer..

Answer (score 13):

I think this is fixed by this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us

More details (for older OS's and .NET versions)

KBs for the IE11 GDR:

- 2836939 .NET 4 -
  Win7SP1/Win2K3SP2/Win2K8R2SP1/Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836940
  .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win2K3SP2/Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836941 .NET 2.0
  SP2 - Win2K3SP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836942 .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win7SP1/Win2K8R2SP1
- 2836943 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win7SP1/Win2K8R2SP1
- 2836945 .NET 2.0 SP2 -
  Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2
- 2836946 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win8RTM/WinRTRTM/Win2K12RTM
- 2836947 .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win8RTM/WinRTRTM/Win2K12RTM

Comment: **It's important to mention** :  I also installed it and nothing worked. - until I renamed `app_browsers` to another name( or delete) - then  - everything worked.

Answer (score 6):

I tried every patch that I've seen listed on the internet, including the ones listed here.  The only thing that actually seemed to work was installing the .NET 4.5 Framework on the server.

Get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Hope this saves someone a few of the hours I've lost on this one.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently using asp.net 4.0 and had this issue for a while.  It first appeared with IPad users, and we solved it by creating a IPad.browser file.  Then this bug appeared for IE11 users.  We installed the KBs above with no luck.  The solution: delete all *.browser files (and even the App_Browsers folder itself).  Now it works!

Comment: You are right. I also installed it and nothing worked. - until I rename app_browsers to another name( or delete)