# __dopostback undefined in IE 11 in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-11

I have my asp.net application running on windows server 2008. I tried to access my application from a client machine with .Net framework installed and from another machine with no .net framework. Both machine have windows 7 installed.

In the machine with .NET framework 4 its throws the error

```
__dopostback undefined
```

in the console.
But when i try to access from the machine with no .NET framework installed it works fine.
I found  a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673649/dopostback-undefined-in-ie-11-on-windows-preview-8-1?rq=1). I have 2 quetions.

**1)** Should i install the required .NET framework fix in the server machine or in the client machine.

**2)** And why the issue crops only in machine with .NET framework.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, that's why you should write: `__doPostBack('your Key', 'some parameter');`

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to install .NET framework 4.5 in your server. So that you don't need to do any installation on client side.

Because its not recommended to ask user to install things on client side. ASP.NET 4.5 resolves all that problems and still your asp.net 4.0 can work in same way as it works. Also there are lots of performance improvement in asp.net 4.5 so its better to install it on server.